# Why 4 dimensional array size 800 x 100 x 100 x 100 work only with allocatable array?

Tags: macos, multidimensional-array, fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I tried to work with 4 dimensional array size 800 x 100 x 100 x 100 but get stuck in this error:

```
/var/folders/cd/jlh3y5md6t70w3h9w747_87c0000gn/T//ccZySij1.s:282:zerofill size (3200000000.) <0! Ignored.
/var/folders/cd/jlh3y5md6t70w3h9w747_87c0000gn/T//ccZySij1.s:282:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 44 (,).
/var/folders/cd/jlh3y5md6t70w3h9w747_87c0000gn/T//ccZySij1.s:283:zerofill size (3200000000.) <0! Ignored.
/var/folders/cd/jlh3y5md6t70w3h9w747_87c0000gn/T//ccZySij1.s:283:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 44 (,).
make: *** [run.out] Error 1
```

But if I use allocatable array instead of normal array I can pass this error.

The question is why?

**Note:** Usual array size 800 x 80 x 80 x 80 still can work.

**Edit from request: Code which use allocatable array**

```
  9     integer :: x_size = 100
 10     integer :: y_size = 100
 11     integer :: z_size = 100
 12     integer :: t_size = 800
 13
 14     real, dimension(:,:,:,:), allocatable :: l1, l2
 15     allocate(l1(t_size, z_size, y_size, x_size), &
 16              l2(t_size, z_size, y_size, x_size))
```

**Edit from request: Code which use normal array**

```
  9     integer :: x_size = 100
 10     integer :: y_size = 100
 11     integer :: z_size = 100
 12     integer :: t_size = 800
 13
 14     real, dimension(t_size, z_size, y_size, x_size) :: l1, l2
```

Comment: Looks like an overflow issue. 3200000000 is a negative number when referenced as a signed 32-bit integer. A 4-dimensional array with bounds of 80 is nearly 60% smaller than the same with bounds of 100. This brings the total below the signed integer limit of 2^31-1.

Comment: Fortran processor is allowed to have an upper limit on the array size. That said, can you try using higher integer kinds? You also should show your code with the `allocate ` statement.

Comment: And what do you mean by "normal array"? You should show that code too and not only the line, but it must be clear where is it placed.

Comment: @VladimirF I mean something like `real, dimension(100, 100, 100, 100) :: l1, l2`

Comment: You should show that code too and not only the line, but it must be clear where is it placed.

Comment: Nevertheless, I assumed you meant a static array and not an autmatic one, but who knows. `mcmodel=medium` might help, but allocatables are generally better.

Comment: [This bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61099) suggests it's a known bug with Apple's assembler.

Comment: The point of my request was to see if it is in a subroutine or in a main program or in a module. You can delete the loops.

Comment: They are in the main program. @VladimirF

Comment: @terces907 To test the Apple bug, try setting the limits on the 3 smaller dimensions to 115. This should be enough to roll the total allocated size past 2^32 and not trigger the bug.